# Detect modalView is from certain UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have one modalView which is presented from two different UIViewController A and B. What I am trying to do is that detecting modalView is from A or B, and do a little bit different action.

I think I can use delegate or other flags to detect it but is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `UIViewController.presentingViewController` when you are showing your modal VC with `UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion`.

Comment: UIViewController.presentingViewController is "The view controller that presented this view controller". My question is how to detect where are you from?

Comment: As is understood it you want to check in your Modal View who presented it. So in your Modal View Controller check its `presentingViewController` if it's of `A` or `B` class. Do you know what I mean? ;) Or did I misunderstand you?